# ElementTree XML parsing from UTF-8 source file

Tags: python, xml, parsing, utf-8

I have this XML file with utf-8 encoding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Items>
 <Item>
 <Cikkszam>00008</Cikkszam>
 <EAN/>
 <Megjegyzes>BISK</Megjegyzes>
 <Leiras1>Bisk Ontario, Dakota szappantartóhoz</Leiras1>
 <Leiras2>műanyag betét</Leiras2>
 <CikkTipus>07  </CikkTipus>
 <ME_>db   </ME_>
 <Tipus>Választható</Tipus>
 <A_ar>338</A_ar>
 <B_ar>0</B_ar>
 <C_ar>0</C_ar>
 <D_ar>0</D_ar>
 <E_ar>0</E_ar>
 <Tenyl_keszl_>0</Tenyl_keszl_>
 <Visszaig_>0</Visszaig_>
 <Diszponalt>0</Diszponalt>
 <Szabad_keszlet>0</Szabad_keszlet>
 </Item>
</Items>
```

I have this Python code:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
#import xml.etree.ElementTree

items = ElementTree().parse('proba.xml'.encode('utf8'))
#items = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('proba.xml')

products = items.findall("Item")
for product in products:
    print product.find("Leiras1").text
```

When I run my script file I got the next error message:

```
C:\Python27>python read_xml_orig.py
Bisk Ontario, Dakota szappantartóhoz
Bisk Álló Wc kefe és papír tartó talpas
Bisk sarok szappantartó króm
Bisk sarok szappantartó króm
Bisk üveg pohár pót
Bisk ONTARIO üveg folyékony
Bisk ONTARIO üveg polc
Bisk ONTARIO dupla
Bisk ONTARIO  rud
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_xml_orig.py", line 7, in <module>
    print product.find("Leiras1").text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0151' in position
 21: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0):

`'proba.xml'.encode('utf8')` encodes the string `'proba.xml'` as UTF-8. It does nothing to the file of the same name.

When the file really is encoded as UTF-8 then your code will work:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

doc = ElementTree().parse('proba.xml')

products = doc.findall("Item")
for product in products:
    print product.find("Leiras1").text
```

which prints this for me

```
Bisk Ontario, Dakota szappantartóhoz
```

**However**, if your file is not really UTF-8 then you might get encoding errors during `.parse()`.

In this case you must figure out what encoding the file is in and correct the XML declaration accordingly. Hint: A likely encoding candidate for Hungarian is `Windows-1250`.